# Overload * operator in python (or emulate it)

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword, unpack

I want to overload the * operator in python. In C++, you can overload the dereference operator, so that you can create a class with a custom way to respond to `*alpha`.

Part of this question is that I don't know exactly, and I mean EXACTLY, what the * operator (unpacking operator as I call it) does.

So how can I overload it, or emulate the overloading of it.

Eventually I want to be able to do: `*alpha` with a custom response and return value.

---

EDIT:

I found the solution thanks to Joe Kington's comment. As `*alpha` unpacks according to `__iter__`, so I defined a simple class that can be inherited from to allow this.

BTW, the reason I want to be able to do this is because I wanted a pretty interface.

```
class Deref:
  def __deref__(self):
    pass

  def __iter__(self):
    yield self.__deref__()

class DerefTest(Deref):
  def __deref__(self):
    return '123cat'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(*DerefTest()) # prints '123cat'
```

---

Eventually I just settled on using another unary operator because the implementation I gave doesn't work in all cases, so I am dissapoint.

Comment: You should be able to do what you want by overloading `__iter__`, though this will affect any iteration through your object.

Comment: The `*` and `**` syntax before parameter names in function calls and definitions isn't considered an operator, per se, and can't be overloaded. (Why do you want to do this?)

Comment: What is the thing upon which you wish to "overload the operator"? For what purpose? Could you give an example use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you understood the unary `*` and `**` "operators" correctly.

They unpack a list/dict into function arguments/keyword arguments. There is nothing else that makes sense in this context. Thus, they cannot be overloaded.

Actually, using them is a syntax error anywhere but in a function declaration/call.

Comment: Actually you *can* use * in at least one other place: in Python 3, you can write `a, *b = 1,2,3` to set a to 1 and b to [2,3].  Kind of a generalization, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, pointee):
        self.pointee = pointee

    def deref(self):
        return self.pointee
```

is not what you want?

Could you be more specific on what the advantage of writing as `*ptr` is, instead of `ptr.deref()` defined above?