# Is there a way to edit the behavior of **<object> in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

This is more of a curiosity than a necessary use case but I would like to edit the following behavior:

```html
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> x={'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}
>>> y={'d':33,'e':45,'c':7}
>>> z={'aa':3,'bb':4,'cc':5}
>>> def foo(a,b,c,cc,**kwargs):
...     print(a,b,c,cc)

>>> map = ChainMap(x,y,z)
>>> map
ChainMap({'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'d': 33, 'e': 45, 'c': 7}, {'aa': 3, 'bb': 4, 'cc': 5})

>>> foo(**map)
3 4 5 5
```

Is it at all possible to change the behavior of `**` do custom things like return the sum of repeated `keys`. In the above case it would print `3 4 12 5` or give the last instance not the first `3 4 7 5`?

Comment: Related:  [Change what the *splat and **splatty-splat operators do to my object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365847/674039)

Comment: thanks that is what I was looking for, also I approve of this person's naming convention. editing `splatty-splat` will be useful

Comment: OK, since it pretty much answers the question I will close as duplicate then.