# What Is **{key:value} Called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, timedelta

I just ran into a situation whereby I need to use a `timedelta`. I have only used `timedelta` once before, and I am using that piece of code as a reference point.

```
timedelta(**{unit_of_measurement:quantity_of_units})
```

**I am simply curious what the `**{var1:var2}` part of the code is called?**

I am new to Python, so I am not sure if it is exclusive to `timedeltas`, `datetime`, or Python in general. There is no mention of it in the `datetime` documentation. I have tried searching Google, but it returns completely irrelevant results.

Comment: Please try to make titles specific enough that someone doesn't need to click through to be able to know what you're asking about. (In this case, I changed "This Piece Of Code" to `**{key:value}`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hard to make it specific when i have no idea what it is lol. i tried to make it as specific as possible

Comment: Showing the actual syntax in the title is more specific than saying "this syntax" or "this code". To someone who's only seen the title, "this code" could be anything.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy duly noted

Comment: It's called splatty splat: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365847/2988730. And no one can ever tell me otherwise!

Comment: Remember, we want your question to help future readers as well as you. A title like "What Is This Unusual Piece of Code Called" is pretty useless in a Google search. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring you never know lol when i searched for ***python **{x:y}*** nothing came up for me o: